# Basic question on notation of partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've seen the (single variable) chain rule written in two ways:

$\left(f(g(x)) \right)'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$ and $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {dy}{dt}\cdot \frac {dt}{dx}$.

The second one is more commonly used later in multivariate calc.

My doubt is: When you use the Leibnitz notation, how do you know where each $\frac {\partial z}{\partial w}$ is evaluated at?
In the single variate chain rule, $\dfrac {dy}{dt}$ is evaluated at $t$, but this is nowhere in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y=y(t)=y(t(x))$ then the rule is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}(x_0)=\frac{dy}{dt}(t(x_0))\frac{dt}{dx}(x_0),$$
for functions in one variable.

For functions on more than one variable
you need to specify them explicitly what you have in mind.

---

As an example in several variables, let us consider 
$$F=F(x,y,z)=F(x(v,w),y(v,w),z(v,w)),$$
so, maybe you are interested in the calculation of $\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}$, 
then
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial v},$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial w},$$
and on evaluation at a point $p=(x(v_0,w_0),y(v_0,w_0,z(v_0,w_0))$ then it would be
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(v_0,w_0)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(p)\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}(v_0,w_0)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(p)\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}(v_0,w_0)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(p)\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}(v_0,w_0).$$

Similarly  for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial w}(v_0,w_0)$.

Comment: Hmm, I was just providing the example of the single variable, which I understand, and was interested in understanding the notation for the case of more variables (mostly two or three).

Comment: i just added an edit to fit your interest

Comment: Ohh, I see, so whenever I have something of the form $F(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, $x_i=g_i(y_1,...,y_s)$ then when I take the derivative with respect to $y_{j}$, the term $\partial F/\partial y_{j}$ is evaluated at the point $p=(x_1(y_1,...,s),...,x_n(y_1,...,y_s))$ while the other terms are evaluated at $(y_1,...,y_s)$, did I understand that correctly? Thanks!

Comment: ok, you got it.